# A question inside First Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sorry if my question may be rudimentary but still I think that my question is not trivial and I need to prove that.

In the proof of First Isomorphism Theorem which is:

> If $ψ : G → H$ is a group homomorphism with $K =ker(ψ)$, then $K$ is normal in $G$. Let $φ:G →G/K$ be the canonical homomorphism. Then there exists a unique isomorphism $η:G/K→ψ(G)$ such that $ψ=ηφ$ ,

I only need to prove that $η$ is onto $ψ(G)$. Clearly, a function $ψ : G → ψ(G)$ is onto, but how can I prove $η$ is onto while its domain is not $G$?

Thanks a lot.

Edit - Well I think I need to prove that if $ψ=η\circ φ$ and $ψ$ and $φ$ is onto, so is $η$ (?) but I don't know how.

Comment: Suppose that $h\in H$ is in the image of $\psi$ but not in the image of $\eta$.  Can you get a contradiction?

Comment: @hardmath -  if $h\in H$ is in the image of $ψ$ but not in the image of $η$, so there must be a map from $G$ to $ψ(G)$ and it's a contradiction; is that enough?

Comment: Yes, and as Alex M. points out, this is essentially a "constructive" argument since we know which argument for $\eta$ will hit $h = \psi(g)$.  I find that setting up the argument as "by contradiction" is often useful in prying up the insight about why a proof can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a constructive method here: if we use hats to denote classes in $G/K$, then define $\eta (\hat g) = \psi (g)$. Note that if $\hat h = \hat g$, then $h g^{-1} \in K$, so $\psi (hg^{-1}) = 1$, so $\psi (g) = \psi (h)$, hence $\eta$ is well defined. Show that it is a morphism (straightforward elementary computation). By construction, since $\hat g = \varphi (g)$, you will have $\eta \circ \varphi = \psi$.